# Will Java mail works in PCF cloud

Tags: cloud-foundry, pivotal-web-services

I have written a service which sends an email using gmail smtp server and trying to deploy it in the PCF cloud. The service is working in my local as it connects to internet to authenticate and sends mails. Now I wonder if it works in PCF as it needs internet to authenticate as well as send email. How it finds internet in PCF cloud?

Answer (score 0):

You may have to use a mail service like [SendGrid](https://sendgrid.com/free/).

Here is a good [article](https://docs.run.pivotal.io/marketplace/services/sendgrid.html) from Pivotal on how to use Sendgrid. If you are on PWS, you can get Sendgrid from the Marketplace.

The other thing you can try is to use `push notification`. 
Here's the [link](https://github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/notifications).

Comment: I don't know how it was functional, I did a push and it was working fine.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes. PWS is a cloud-native PAAS, sending an email via a service is a cloud-native method of inter-operating with other systems.

If on another hand you were using native system facility like sendmail, you would violating cloud-native tenants and your solution would not scale correctly with PWS.